# Extending Akemann's Non-Commutative Urysohn Lemma

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-topology

Assume $A$ is a C*-algebra and $p,q\in A^{**}$ are compact projections.

> Can we always find $a,b\in A^1_+$ with $p\leq a$, $q\leq b$ and $||pq||=||ab||$?

Note if $||pq||=1$ this is immediate, while if $||pq||=0$ this follows from Akemann's non-commutative Urysohn Lemma - see ["A Gelfand representation theory for C*-algebras"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102969765) Lemma III.1 (Pacific J. Math. 39 (1971), no. 1, 1--11).

Comment: There was a big investigation on projections in operator algebras made by D. Blecher and his students. This might help http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.5347.pdf, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.5171.pdf

Comment: Blecher et al have certainly done some great work extending the non-commutative topological theory of C*-algebras to more general Banach algebras.  But as far as I can tell, their extensions of Akemann's non-commutative Urysohn lemma (like Theorem 2.1 of the first article you mention) still require the given projections to commute.